# Discord.py/ Not all lines are written

Tags: python, string, discord.py, new-operator

I have a problem creating discord bots. The problem is when I use the `.idea` (idea text) command, only the first phrase of the idea is transferred to the outgoing embed.

Code:

```
@bot.command(pass_contxt=True)
async def идея(ctx,arg):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit = 1)
    emb = discord.Embed(title=f'`Начато голосование на идею` ',
    description='Идея: ' + str(arg),
    colour=discord.Color.purple()
    )
    emb.set_footer(text = str(ctx.message.author))
    message = await ctx.send(embed=emb)
    await message.add_reaction('✅')
    await message.add_reaction('❌')
    print('>>Была отправлена идея: ' + str(arg))
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Have a look at the official discord.py FAQ -> [Consume all arguments](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#why-do-my-arguments-require-quotes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, it would be better sending your code using the code block formatting.

[image: code_block]

Then, related to your commands, `arg` should be a string - `arg: str`.

Your new command:

```py
@bot.command()
async def идея(ctx, *, arg: str): 
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit = 1)
    emb = discord.Embed(
        title=f'Начато голосование на идею ',
        description='Идея: ' + arg,
        colour=discord.Color.purple())
    emb.set_footer(text = str(ctx.message.author))

    message = await ctx.send(embed=emb)
    await message.add_reaction('✅')
    await message.add_reaction('❌')
    print('>>Была отправлена идея: ' + arg)
```

Please check this question accepted to help other users (also upvoting would be great!)

Have a great day!